# Размер FloatingActionButton - Flutter

Tags: вёрстка, flutter, dart

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    label: Text('Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),),
    icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white,)
)
```

Как изменить размеры кнопки? Пробовал padding.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateExeat()));
          },
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          label: Text('Add',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      )
```

Поместите FloatingActionButton в Container